# Can't change audio source

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I've seen other topics but their codes are really complex. I want mines to be simple so I can comprehend it easily. I thought it would be easy but it turned out to be hard. Apparently, you cant change audio source by changing it's attributes. I want the audio source to change when the checkbox has changed, and then it will change into the corresponding audio file.

HTML

```
<select id="ccw" onblur="check()">
<option>Lobby</option>
<option>Autumn</option>
<option>Winter</option>
<option>Spring</option>
<option>Summer</option>
</select>
<audio class="stage10" controls>
<source src="default.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Audio element not supported by your browser
</audio>
```

JS

```
var songs = [
//lobby
"default.mp3",
//autumn
"fall.mp3",
//winter
"the ice age.mp3",
//spring
"AHHHH ITS BEEEEEEEES.mp3",
//summer
"Da Summa of 1989 or was it 1998 i dont know.mp3"

//please do not take notes of the file's names
]

$(function() {
    $('#ccw').on('change', check)
})
function check() {
    var ccw = $('#ccw').val()
    if (ccw == "Autumn") {
        $('#stage10 source').attr('src', songs[1])
    } else if (ccw == "Winter") {
        $('#stage10 source').attr('src', songs[2])
    } else if (ccw == "Spring") {
        $('#stage10 source').attr('src', songs[3])
    } else if (ccw == "Summer") {
        $('#stage10 source').attr('src', songs[4])
    } else {
        $('#stage10 source').attr('src', songs[0])
    }
    $('audio')[10].load() // this wasn't here before, but i tried testing with it.
}
```

I am unsure why it does not work. Someone please help me!

Answer (score 0):

"#stage10" is an ID selector, replace it with ".stage10" if you want to select element by class:

```
function check() {
    var ccw = $('#ccw').val()
    if (ccw == "Autumn") {
        $('.stage10 source').attr('src', songs[1])
    } else if (ccw == "Winter") {
        $('.stage10 source').attr('src', songs[2])
    } else if (ccw == "Spring") {
        $('.stage10 source').attr('src', songs[3])
    } else if (ccw == "Summer") {
        $('.stage10 source').attr('src', songs[4])
    } else {
        $('.stage10 source').attr('src', songs[0])
    }
    $('audio')[10].load() // this wasn't here before, but i tried testing with it.
}
```